# Adding a Root Level "Metadata" Field to an ElasticSearch Index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a standard ElasticSearch index keyed by a primary key with a repeating document structure under each key.

I have a "datasource id" field which applies to every single document in the index (meaning it would be the same value in every single document). Is there a way to add this information at the "root" level of the index as opposed to inserting the same value into every document?

Comment: What you want to do sounds a lot like a join. you have a common identifier and some data associated with it. ES is denormalised for performance reasons and I believe you would usually do that by hooking something like logstash into your pipeline in order to enhance the data you try to index.

Comment: So are you having a separate index for each data source?  Or are you looking to use the same index to plug in data from multiple data sources?

Comment: A separate index for each datasource. At the index level, I needed to capture the "datasourceID.' Entering this in the `_meta` field as @Val suggested met the use case.

Comment: you could use an `id` field to set your unique Value, Elastic Will Use id field as Unique Identifier, if you attempt to add duplicate it will throw Duplicate Version Error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`_meta` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-meta-field.html). When you create your index you can add the database ID in it:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
          "_meta": {
            "databaseID": "MY-DB-ID"
          }
      },
      "properties": {
        all your field go here...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Val - that ended up being exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually changed in ES7, you can drop _doc i.e.

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
      "_meta": {
          "databaseID": "MY-DB-ID"
      },
      "properties": {
         # all your field go here...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't drop the nesting the data within `_doc` you will get a 400 error similar to this:

```
{'error': {'root_cause': [{'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': 'Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [_doc : {_meta={databaseID=MY-DB-ID!}}]'}], 'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': 'Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [_doc : {_meta={databaseID=MY-DB-ID!}}]', 'caused_by': {'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': 'Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [_doc : {_meta={databaseID=MY-DB-ID!}}]'}}, 'status': 400}
```